# Java How can I display and search the same value in a txt file so all the records are scanned and displayed if value is in the record

Tags: java

Here is my quest, I have the same value in records in a text file. 
But I only get to find  the first one and to display the first one. 
How can I find all the record with that value and display them. 
Here is the code,

```
package projectsby;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.Scanner;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

    public class Find {
    private static Scanner o;

        public void openFile(){
            try{
                o = new Scanner(new File("/Users/e.h.j.hofman/NetBeansProjects/Projectsby/src/projectsby/Projects.txt"));
            }

    catch(Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Could not find file");   
    }}

        /**
         *
         * @param searchTerm
         * @param filepath
         */
        public void readEntries(String searchTerm, String filepath){

        boolean found = false;
        String Project = "";
        String omschrijving = "";
        String BU= ""; 
        String afdeling = "";

        try
        {
            o = new Scanner(new File(filepath));
            //o.useDelimiter("[ \n]");
            while(o.hasNext()
                    //&& !found )
            {

                Project = o.next();
                omschrijving = o.next();
                BU = o.next();
                afdeling = o.next();

                if(Project.equalsIgnoreCase(searchTerm))
                {
                    found = true; }
            }
           if (found) 
           {
```

Here i suspect it will help when there is some kind of while loop.

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog
(null,"Project: " + Project + " " +omschrijving + "\nBU: " 
+ BU + "\nAfdeling: " +afdeling);
           } else {
                       JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Project not found");
        }}
        catch(Exception e)
      {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error");
      }}
    public void closeFile(){
        o.close();
      }}
```

Comment: What's your input? What do you see now? What output are you expecting?

Answer (score 0):

It is a little hard to tell from your code formatting but the block of code in the "if (found)" statement will only be executed at the end of the file since it is outside the while loop.  Maybe that code should be moved to the "if(Project.equalsIgnoreCase(searchTerm))" statement instead.  Then it will execute on every record in the file, if the searchTerm is found.

Then there is no reason for the "found" boolean.

```
 while (o.hasNext()) {
    ...
    if(Project.equalsIgnoreCase(searchTerm)) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog ...
    }
 }
```